# MYSQL Between clause

Tags: php, mysql

I am selecting last names from a database based on a range of letters. Everything works fine except with names beginning with Z. Apparently, the BETWEEN clause does not include Z, the way it includes the letters in other ranges. Is there a simple way of handling this?

```
$range1 = "V";
$range2 = "Z";
$sql = "SELECT id,first,last FROM users WHERE last BETWEEN '$range1' AND '$range2' ORDER BY last ASC";
```

This query will not include names beginning with the letter Z. But if the range were A-G, names with G will be included.

Comment: Do you have only _single_ letters in `last`? Because `G` is `<= 'G'`, but `'Gandthensomething' > 'G'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental issue is that the system converts the character data to the ascii equivalents.  When it does this Z < but not equal to Zebra  so you need the next ascii character beyond z.  if Z is 90 then [ is 91.  So if you want everything between CAPITAL A and all extensions of Z then you need it to be less than [ as range 2.

Alternatively just compare the first letters instead of the whole strings.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I simply made my range V-Zz. The extra z ensures all subsequent characters after the first Z are included. Thank you.

Comment: That would work as well so long as you don't have a last name of ZZa. or Z'cho you get the picture.